# From TensorFlow to ONNX - save/freeze graph or convert pkl?

Tags: python, tensorflow, onnx

Newbie question on the best way to go from TensorFlow to ONNX: what is the better (and/or easier) way between the two listed below?

1. Freeze/save the network --> store a .pb file --> convert the .pb into .onnx (I am struggling with this)
2. Convert a .pkl snapshot into .onnx. I haven't found any material on this, so any tip is welcome!

Comment: if you are asking this for serving. why not use tfx https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/guide/serving

Comment: I'm gonna check it out. I just need to get an onnx, to be used by tensorrt... Do you think tf serving could be the way to go?

Comment: Did you have a look at https://github.com/onnx/tensorflow-onnx then?

Comment: I should've wrote tf serving earlier. I never worked with TensorRT but are you sure you need to convert to onnx for that? There are some tensorflow tensorRT tutorials you might wanna check out and there is a repo for the integration https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorrt

Comment: yeah, I am aware of tf2onnx, but I am having issues converting my frozen model. my problem is a bit unusual and I am forced to get an onnx (or something else that can be imported using tensorrt) as a final output.